# Add address bar to Java WebView

Tags: java, webview

I have this code that creates a Java window that displays web pages, however I want the user to be able to go to other web pages with their own free will. So I was wondering if it is possible to put in an address bar so user can input a site address and go there, as well as putting in forward and backward buttons. Here is my Java code:

```
package stallionbrowser;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 *
 * @author seanguy4
 */
public class StallionBrowser extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");        
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

final WebView browser = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

public Browser() {
    //apply the styles
    getStyleClass().add("browser");
    // load the web page
    webEngine.load("http://www.stallionware.weebly.com");
    //add the web view to the scene
    getChildren().add(browser);

    }
    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 500;
    }
}
```